# What is the underlying implement of Character that maps to ASCII?

Tags: java, c++, mapping, ascii

I don't know how  JAVA/C++ can  get the ASCII code of a character so fast.

I want to know the underlying mapping mechanism.

For example, I know that 'a' equals 96, but I want to know that when JAVA/C++ sees this character, how does it convert 'a' to 96?

Thanks a lot!

I mean, I know that 'a' is actually 01100000 in computer memory, but how does JAVA or C++ knows that 'a' is 01100000, rather than 0100001 or other number? How can it knows the digit of 'a' so fast?

Comment: What is JAVA/C++? Java and C++ are completely different languages.

Comment: Do you mean on runtime or compilation time? Java doesn't use ASCII much. And a character is only a representation (for your screen) of a whatsoever numeric value in memory...

Comment: In Java char is just an unsighed short and represened by 16bits or 2 bytes. It doesn't really do any mapping, the symbols are just bits and bytes. So, even if you see 'a' in your editor it is still 96 in the binary form.

Comment: How does it know that it should convert 'a' to 01100000, rather than 01100001 or other number?

Answer (score 2):

The reality, is that it doesn't "convert" a character to ASCII so quickly. The character is stored **as** ASCII, so no conversion is necessary.

That is to say, the computer stores 96 in memory, not 'a'. The 'a' you see on your screen is only for display purposes.

Therefore, when your program says:

```
char ch = 'a';
```

In reality, this is equivalent to writing:

```
char ch = 96;
```

Think of `char` as just an integer type.

So when you print a string, your computer reads each character, eg. 96, and looks up what it should draw for the character 96. This changes depending on your font. So it checks what the font's entry for 96 is, and copies the pixels, or draws some vector graphics corresponding to that. Therefore, the 'a' you see displayed takes the computer quite a long time to display (it doesn't take long, but possibly still thousands of clock cycles).

Comment: Thanks! I mean, how does the computer know that it should save 96 for 'a'?  Why not 97? 104? 88?

Comment: @NormanBai The computer doesn't know it is an 'a' or whatever else. It sees only 96, 97, 104 or 88.

Comment: When you type the characters 'a' into your source code file, the compiler sees the integers 39 96 39 (where 39 is the single quote). Your keyboard converts the key-press you make into these numbers (they are hard-wired).

Comment: @NormanBai it is by specifications, ASCII is a standard constant table that is agreed upon long ago.
'a' could be any other number [0, 255] (or 127 for traditional ASCII), but as a justification, 97 is 0x61 in hexa, which makes sense as it is pretty round number to start the letter set from... (same for 'A' = 65 = 0x41)

Comment: @ronalchn thanks a lot! And I know that the keyboard can translate 'a' now. How can it translate Japanese or Chinese ? We don't have their character on the keyboard...

Answer (score -2):

Try this code for Java.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("a".getBytes()[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not answer the question.